# jquery animate continuous animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I know there are alot of questions already asked about jquery animation but I have not found anything that has worked for me yet.

I have seen alot of examples where people use the .animate call with a function passed in as a "complete" parameter but none that also have a step function.  I know this shouldn't matter but I believe it is what makes my case different.

```
    var animateWelcome = function(targetElement,speed){
        $('#animatewelcome').animate(
            {
                r:360
            },
            {
                duration:speed,
                step:function(now,fx)
                {
                    if(fx.prop == 'r') r = now;
                    $('#animatewelcome').css('transform','rotateY('+r+'deg)');
                },
                complete:function()
                {
                    alert('done');
                    r = 0;
                    $('#animatewelcome').css('transform','');
                    animateWelcome(this,speed);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

It will rotate the first time ONLY.  The "done" alert does not appear.
Hopefully it is a dumb syntax error.  Anyone?

Comment: The console will tell you if it is a 'dumb syntax error'.  Please create a jsfiddle.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what do you want...

Comment: @mambrow no console output.  Creating jsfiddle

Comment: Is jsfiddle down? I get a server error when trying to access jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am trying to get the "animateWelcome" element to continually rotate.

Comment: jsfiddle's been down for me all morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happened:
The alert was being silenced. The complete function was being entered.

What needs to be done to get the element to keep rotating is that the element needs to be deleted and readded:

```
        var newp = document.createElement('p');
        newp.innerHTML = "text";
        newp.id = 'animatewelcome';
        $('#animatewelcome').remove();
        document.getElementById('animatewrapper').appendChild(newp);
        animateWelcome($('#animatewelcome'),7500);
```

My guess is this only needs to be done if an element is rotating, and simpler animations do not need this 'trick'